# Simple PHP XSS / Urlencode Question

Tags: php, xss, urlencode

I have an email address param where email addresses are passed un-encoded like so:

http://domain/script?email=test+test@gmail.com

What PHP escaping/encoding will let me safely display the email address on an input field on the page?

Everything I tried causes the encoded chars to show up instead of the user-friendly email address (i.e. test%2Btest%40test.com)

**Update - here's what I've tried:**

Going from *?email=test+test@gmail.com* to:

```
urlencode($_GET['email']) = test+test%40test.com (@ sign is encoded)
htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']) = test test@test.com (lost the +)
htmlspecialchars(urlencode($_GET['email']) = test+test%40test.com (@ sign encoded)
```

Recall that I'm trying to take the unencoded url email param and safely output it into the value of an input field while keeping plus signs intact.

Maybe I should try this?

```
str_replace("%40", "@", htmlspecialchars(urlencode($_GET['email'])))
```

Comment: The best way is firstly urldecode it, then htmlspecialchars it :) $email = htmlspecialchars( urldecode( $_GET['email'] ) ); now you can use $email ;)

Comment: No, I don't think you understand. The email address is sent un-encoded.

Comment: Try htmlspecialchars as ahmet2106 pointed out.

Comment: This doesn't work in that the plus sign still gets converted to a space. In other words, the input field looks like "test test@gmail.com".

Comment: It gets converted to a space because `+` in a URL *represents a space*. You'll have to URL-encode everything before putting it into a URL if you want to preserve spaces etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
str_replace("%40", "@", htmlspecialchars(urlencode($_GET['email'])))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to safely output it in the value of an input field, you need to htmlencode it first with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Example :

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']); ?>"
```

Note : If you aren't using double quote around what you are output, you need to apply more escaping. [This page](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes) explains it all.

Comment: This doesn't work in that the plus sign still gets converted to a space. In other words, the input field looks like "test test@gmail.com".

Comment: @Josha that's because you didn't encode your email properly in first place. In an URL `+` is a space. What the server receive is `test test@gmail.com` not `test+test@gmail.com`. If you want to make sure a parameter is properly encoded for an URL you need to escape it with [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `urldecode()`?  That's what converts %40, %2B, etc. back into normal characters.

Answer (score 0):

use `emailaddress = urldecode($_GET['email']);` as Kevin suggested. it will do whatever you need.

Comment: There is nothing to decode as the email address is sent un-encoded. Therefore urldecode does nothing!

Answer (score 0):

What if you validate the email and write it as it was, if only an email address is acceptable?